Flutter App Link from Firebase Webapp won't open app
I simply want my app to open, when a user is tapping on a link of my website, but it will always just go to the website.
I already added this to my manifest:
    <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="false" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />

    <data android:host="wishlist-88d58.web.app" />
</intent-filter>

What am I missing here? I also a assetlinks.json inside my .well-known:
[
  {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target" : 
    { 
      "namespace": "android_app", 
      "package_name": "my_package_name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["my_finger_print"] 
    }
  }
]

extra info
The redirection was working before when I had another URL. Now I simply want to change the URL but it's not working anymore, but still working when using the old url.

I got it working by copying the assetlink.json from my other website. There were two more fingerprints included.
Can't tell where exactly they are coming from, because in the Play Console it suggested me to use the above one.
But if you have the same issue, probably something is wrong with your fingerprints.
